# RecyclerView with groups of images from JSON

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-recyclerview

im really struggling with getting my head around using a Recyclerview in my application.

Currently i have a layout that contains a gridview. This gridview is populated with images. The paths for the images are from a webservice, provided in JSON.

This all works pretty well, however...

I want to organise the images on the screen into different groups which are provided by the web service. I was thinking about creating a child view that has the following layout:

-textview (header)
-gridview (list of images)

This childview is then recycled over and over depending on how many categories there are.

I also need advice on the structure of the JSON file in order to make the input easier. My current JSON file looks like this:

```
[
{
path: "upload/images/1430572021716.jpg"
},
{
path: "upload/images/1430574003703.jpg"
},
{
path: "upload/images/1430574124119.jpg"
}
]
```

I was thinking about using a nested array like this example i found

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

I really am confused here. From what i understand a RecyclerView with a GridviewLayout should be able to accept images directly and handle the header of the group without the need for rafts of code.

Its a bit of a ramble but its where im at.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about this wrong. I'm quite certain you're not supposed to nest AdapterViews (ListView, GridView, RecyclerView) so the way I would implement this is by using a Recycler View with section headers. When you create your Recycler view adapter, make sure to have multiple types of viewholders. Then create your own layout manager to arrange your headers etc.

```
public class Recyclerk extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeClass> {
    @Override
    public Object onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         //This is where you decide whether it's a header view or a sub item
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Object holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        //This is where you want to tell recycler whether it's a 
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: cheers for the heads up. its put  me on the right path. Ill post the full implementation when i get it going. Fairly new  to this android lark, but im getting there